# How to define FPFile object

Tags: filepicker

I want to use the read API of filepicker: https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#read.

I want the input parameter value to be a FPFile object, but they don't provide a sample on how to define it.

I tried their sample code but I get an error:

```
Uncaught FilepickerException: Cannot read given input: [object Object],[object Object]. Not a url, file input, DOM File, or FPFile object.
```

I already used filepicker.pick but the error above still occurs.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The filepicker.io read API takes a few different options as parameters. For instance, you can pass in an FPFile from a filepicker.pick call, i.e.

```
filepicker.pick(function(fpfile){
    filepicker.read(fpfile, function(contents){});
});
```

Or a URL, which must allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, i.e.

```
filepicker.read("http://www.allow-crossdomain.com", function(contents){});
```

Or a DOM file object or `<input type="file">`, i.e.

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
    filepicker.read(this, function(contents){});
});
```